# How Cassandra ensures high availability?

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, fallback

I want to understand that how Cassandra ensures high availability. What I know is when we query Cassandra database for data, a node called coordinator route the query to the appropriate Cassandra node in the cluster with the required data.
But what if the node which we specify in JDBC connection URL (Which I think will act as coordinator in the cluster, please make me correct if I am wrong) itself down?
In this case how come Cassandra ensures high availability?

Perhaps we as a developer must provide fallback mechanism for that?

Answer (score 4):

In a Cassandra cluster all nodes are equal. There are no masters or coordinators at the cluster level. When you connect to a cluster you usually specify one or more nodes to connect to, but once the driver has connected it can find out about the other nodes. This means that if the first node it connected to goes down, it knows about the other nodes and can connect to one of them instead.

If a query is sent to a node which itself does not host the requested data (or a consistency level higher than one is specified), that node acts as a coordinator for the query, but that is a temporary role, and any node can take that role for any query.

There are even drivers, such as Astyanax, that connect to multiple nodes and try to figure out which node contains the requested data and use the connection to that node to do the query, in order to minimize the query time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But Astyanax seems to be a higher level wrapper arround cassandra. I want to use pure JDBC connection to interact with cassandra. What will be the case in that ?

Comment: The Cassandra JDBC client (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) isn't as advanced as Astyanax or the other mid-level drivers like Hector or Pelops, so I guess you're out of luck as to automatic reconnection. However, if your application knows about a few of the nodes in the cluster, it can just try to connect to them in turn until it finds one that's up. Since no node is special it doesn't matter which it connects to in the end.